# Android Service stops after some time

Tags: java, android, github, android-service, android-fragmentactivity

I am using [this code](https://gist.github.com/daichan4649/5352944) as a sample for my project to show a fragment on lock screen but it only works till the main activity is not destroyed (not removed from recents) and sometime only works for sometime and than it stops showing fragment on screen..

How can I run a service for all time ? also does new APIs supports it ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

initialize the service in the manifest and the you have to call the service as below in the start button

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, AnotherService.class);
        i.setAction("C.ACTION_START_SERVICE");
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            startForegroundService(i);
        }
        else
        {
            startService(i);
        }
```

then you have to start the service just like below

```
public class AnotherService extends Service {
static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 543;
public AnotherService() {
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
   if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
        startMyOwnForeground();
    else
        startForeground(1, new Notification());
        
   //your code here
    

   
}

@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
private void startMyOwnForeground() {

    String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "example.permanence";
    String channelName = "Background Service";
    NotificationChannel chan = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, channelName, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_NONE);
    chan.setLightColor(Color.BLUE);
    chan.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE);


    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    assert manager != null;
    manager.createNotificationChannel(chan);

    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
    Notification notification = notificationBuilder.setOngoing(true)
            .setContentTitle("App is running in background")
            .setPriority(NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_MIN)
            .setCategory(Notification.CATEGORY_SERVICE)

            .build();
    startForeground(2, notification);
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    return START_STICKY;
    //return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}


@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

if you done the service then you have to change the stop button code with this in your activity where you want to stop

```
stopService(new Intent(YourActivity.this, AnotherService.class));
```